# ExtJs dynamically setting grid cell value according to other cells

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a grid (with MVC model), in which there are couple of columns, in which the value depends on other cells value. I used the columns renderer property, which worked well in the beginning. But if a columns value depends on another columns value, which was also rendered dynamically, then I cannot get the value of that cell with the record.get() for obvious reasons.

I shouldn't be just rendering a cells value, but I should actually set the value. 
What would be the correct way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add methods to your model to figure out the value of the other cells.

Example, if you have `interestRate` and `loanPeriod` properties in your model, then you could add a method to your model such as `getMonthlyPayment()`

In your grid column renderer:

```
renderer: function(value, meta, record){
  return record.getMonthlyPayment();
}
```

You don't need an actual model property to have a grid column with a `renderer`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks a million! Still need a lot to learn.